# Will md5(file_contents_as_string) equal md5_file(/path/to/file)?

Tags: php, md5, md5-file

If I do:

`<?php echo md5(file_get_contents("/path/to/file")) ?>`

...will this always produce the same hash as:

`<?php echo md5_file("/path/to/file") ?>`

Comment: Hm, can't say for sure, but if the file contains a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and the string doesn't then the hashes will not be equal.

Comment: [in response to deleted comment] I could try it out myself. I'm just worried that if I get a match and I start comparing md5() to md5_file() there might be issues down the line that produce different hashes - maybe to do with php_ini directives or some such thing way over my head that will be a nightmare to debug/identify.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes they return the same:

```
var_dump(md5(file_get_contents(__FILE__)));
var_dump(md5_file(__FILE__));
```

which returns this in my case:

```
string(32) "4d2aec3ae83694513cb9bde0617deeea"
string(32) "4d2aec3ae83694513cb9bde0617deeea"
```

Edit:
Take a look at the source code of both functions: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/md5.c (Line 47 & 76). They both use the same functions to generate the hash except that the `md5_file()` function opens the file first.

2nd Edit: 
Basically the `md5_file()` function generates the hash based on the file contents, not on the file meta data like the filename. This is the same way `md5sum` on Linux systems work.
See this example:

```
pr@testumgebung:~# echo foobar > foo.txt
pr@testumgebung:~# md5sum foo.txt
14758f1afd44c09b7992073ccf00b43d  foo.txt
pr@testumgebung:~# mv foo.txt bar.txt
pr@testumgebung:~# md5sum bar.txt
14758f1afd44c09b7992073ccf00b43d  bar.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`md5_file` command just hashs the *content* of a file with md5.

If you refer to the old md5_file PHP implementation (but the principle is still the same) [source](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_PHP_Compat__PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3CompatFunctionmd5_file.php.html) :

```
function php_compat_md5_file($filename, $raw_output = false)
{
// ...
// removed protections

 if ($fsize = @filesize($filename)) {
        $data = fread($fh, $fsize);
    } else {
        $data = '';
        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $data .= fread($fh, 8192);
        }
    }

    fclose($fh);

    // Return
    $data = md5($data);
    if ($raw_output === true) {
        $data = pack('H*', $data);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

So if you hash with `md5` any string or content, you will always get the same result as `md5_file` (for the same encoding and file content).

In that case, if you hash by md5 the content of a file with `file_get_content()` or if you use `md5_file` or even if you use `md5` command with the same content as your file content, you will always get the same result.

By example, you could change the file name of a file, and for two different files, with the same content, they will produce the same md5 hash.

By example:
Considering two files containing "stackoverflow" (without the quotes) named 1.txt and 2.txt

```
md5_file("1.txt");
md5_file("2.txt");
```

would output

```
73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc
```

You will have the exact same result if you `md5("stackoverflow")` or if you `md5(file_get_contents("1.txt"))` or `md5(file_get_contents("1.txt")).`

Comment: The Source you're referring to is an old PHP implementation of the function. But the explanation is good.

Comment: Do you have the new link? I don't have a free internet access and so many websites are blocked here. If you have the new source, I will update my post.

Comment: @pier-alexandre-bouchard he posted a link to the php source code in question in his own answer. :)

Comment: @damianb I was talking about PHP md5_file implementation from PHP source.

Comment: There is no newer implementation of this in PHP because it became part of the PHP distribution and was rewritten in C a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

> based on the file contents, not on the file metadata like the BOM or filename

That's not correct about BOM.
BOM is a part of file content, you can see its three bytes in any non-unicode file editor.

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer your quote is from, not an answer on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I tried it for several times.
In my case, result for:

```
<?php echo md5(file_get_contents("1.php")) ?>
<br/>
<?php echo md5_file("1.php") ?>
```

Produce output as:

```
660d4e394937c10cd1c16a98f44457c2
660d4e394937c10cd1c16a98f44457c2
```

Which seems equivalent on both lines.